# How do I access these JSON values?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to access JSON values. This is the JSON object:

```
       {
   "attrs": {
      "width": 1728,
      "height": 787,
      "dragabble": true
   },
   "className": "Stage",
   "children": [
      {
         "attrs": {},
         "className": "Layer",
         "children": [
            {
               "attrs": {
                  "stroke": "green",
                  "strokeWidth": "5",
                  "points": [
                     348,564.125
                  ]
               },
               "className": "Line"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

And I am trying to use these values, like points, here:

```
socket.on("canvas-data", function(data){
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
      if(isDrawing) return;
      setIsDrawing(true);
      clearInterval(interval);
      var obj = JSON.parse(data);
      setStageData(obj);
      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      var lines = new Konva.Line(
      {
        stroke: stageData.stroke,
        strokeWidth: stageData.strokeWidth,
        points: stageData.points
      })
    layer.add(lines);

    stageEl.current.add(layer);

    }, 200)
  })
```

`data` is the JSON string, I tried to parse `data` into `obj`, set my `stageData` to `obj` and then set the corresponding JSON attributes to the values like `stroke`, `strokeWidth` and `points`. This doesn't work however, they're undefined. How do I access them?

(I also tried skipping the step where I set my `stageData` to `obj`, and just use `obj.stroke` instead of `stageData.stroke` etc.)

Comment: I would advise you try and console.log(obj) and try and see what it display on your cnosole. From there it's easy to debug

Comment: @Solar yes I did that already. It says [Object object]. When I try, for example obj[0] it says undefined and so on. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What exactly is your `setStageData()` method doing?

Comment: console shouldn't bring [Object object] unless it means that the data variable is an object itself not a string. So I think you need to remove the JSON.parse(data) line. 
Just try and console.log(data) itself and see if it brings out the result, if it does, just work with it.

Comment: @Cornul11 it just assigns an array to the array stageData

Comment: @Ninini, perhaps the scope of those vars aren't working properly.

Comment: console shouldn't bring [Object object] unless it means that the data variable is an object itself not a string or maybe you're using alert. So I think you need to remove the JSON.parse(data) line. 
Just try and console.log(data) itself and see if it brings out the result, if it does, just work with it.

Comment: @Solar yeah, when I delete the parse line, it gives me just a string. But I really need the actual values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just skip using `setStageData()` and use the parsed object directly if you wish, or just name the parsed object `stageData` by default.
In any case, when you have nested objects and values in an Object, you access them by using the correct index, in your case, it would look this way:

```
socket.on("canvas-data", function(data) {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (isDrawing) return;
    setIsDrawing(true);
    clearInterval(interval);
    var stageData = JSON.parse(data);
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var lines = new Konva.Line(
      {
        stroke: stageData.children[0].children[0].attrs.stroke,
        strokeWidth: stageData.children[0].children[0].attrs.strokeWidth,
        points: stageData.children[0].children[0].attrs.points
      });
    layer.add(lines);

    stageEl.current.add(layer);

  }, 200);
})
```

Doesn't look very nice, but it works. You can always use [this](https://www.convertjson.com/json-path-list.htm) app called JSON Path list, which shows you all the possible paths and their values in a JSON object.